# SOAP WebService objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

Customer implement soap webservice, and give me url of this service. There is this text on url:

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to
>   call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the
>   command line with the following syntax:
>
> `svcutil.exe http://server/?wsdl`
>
> This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains
>   the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use
>   the generated client class to call the Service. For example: ...

I must implement client application on objective-c. Questions:

1) Is this service working? Or I must ask customer to do actions on his server(`svcutil.exe http://server/?wsdl`). Does he should sent me generated files?

2) What steps should I do to implement client of this service?

3) Should I work with WebService Core Framework? How to include it to my iOS project?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

dont use any tools which will generate files for you, instead follow this tuturial, you will get all the information you need, http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

And you should ask your customer to provide you the soap requests so that u can parse them.How to parse? is given in the above link.

Best Luck